# Simplest way for understanding MongoDB iphone

Tags: ios, mongodb

What is the simplest way of understanding about mongoDB? i know there's something called as NuMongo wrapper to to interact with mongoDB, but yet its not yet clear in my head. Can some please share the knowledge ?

Thanks

Comment: What a poor question. Google for "MongoDB NuMongo" returns zero results. So what's the point. Put some webservice in front of MongoDB in call the webservice from your iPhone through the related iPhone API...your question/point is?

Comment: I know i have alternative methods. But i wanted to know if any one here has used it and if i cud know about more about it. And i don't mind if its a poor question because its a part of my leaning process. I'm still a 5 month old programmer. thanks for your help though :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly accessing a MongoDB database from a mobile device is probably not a good idea. The main limitation is that the Mongo wire protocol has no encryption.

You can build an application server as middleware, in [almost any language you like](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/).

That said, [ObjCMongoDB](https://github.com/noa--/ObjCMongoDB) (of which I'm author) has support for iOS, so if you decide you want to give it a go anyway, you can.

If you want to write an application server on Mac OS using Objective-C, you can also use ObjCMongoDB for that, along with something like [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer).

Answer (score 1):

An very simple way is to set up a Rails Application with some mongoDB PlugIn, e.g. mongomapper and in Rails you can define the web service to communicate with the iPhone.

These links are very good to understand Rails and mongomapper:

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

[MongoMapper Documentation](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/)